# Android return the value back to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a mainActivity with a editText, text view and a button. The user inputs a number clicks the button another activity opens and converts the user input (with some random calculation, doesn’t really matter) and returns it to the mainActivity where it’s shown in the TextView. 
But no matter what it won't show the value in the textView back in the MainActivity. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

**MainActivity**

```
 public void sendMessage(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    Intent third = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
    third.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivityForResult(third, 1);
}



 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(requestCode == 1){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String msg = data.getStringExtra("result");

            converted.setText(msg);

        }if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            String msg = ("something went wrong");
            converted.setText(msg);
        }

     }
}
```

SecondActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

    Intent get = getIntent();
    String msg = get.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    int result = Integer.parseInt(msg) +2;
    //String j = Double.toString(a);
        get.putExtra("result", result);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, get);
        finish();


}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: ohh, sorry!! I've edited my main message now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in `ThirdActivity` make this:

```
Intent resultIntent = getIntent();
resultIntent.putExtra("result","msg");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent)
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether you are doing this in your SecondActivity

```
getIntent().putExtra("data", "your data");
setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
finish();
```

Comment: thanks! I realized that my problem was trying to launch two activities with one button, apparently it doesn't work like that. Thank you!